# Ionic textarea input shift+enter to array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a textarea input fiel in my form

```
 <form [formGroup]="addCRCCardForm" (ngSubmit)="createCard(addCRCCardForm.value)" autocomplete="off">
 ...

 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Attributes and operations* </ion-label>
   <ion-textarea type="text" formControlName="responsibilities"></ion-textarea>
 </ion-item>
```

I expect my user to enter values on each new line in this textarea e.g.

```
Name
Age
Gender
```

In my component I want to parse this input and convert it into an array i.e. `["Name", "Age", "Gender"]` which then I am again displaying in my template as a list.

How to achieve this?

Comment: after getting value from textarea split those using space and you will get values in array format, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: using space doesn't help in this case, shift+enter is different perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be resolved using basic javascript

```
var texts = [];
var txtBox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
var lines = txtBox.value.split("\n");

for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        texts.push(lines[i]);
    }
```